# CentOS7 Application Installer not working. Why?

Tags: centos, software-installation

Using the graphical 'Application Installer' in CentOS 7, any application I attempt to install is met with a dialog box containing:

> **Sorry, this did not work**
>
> Installation of QtCreator failed. If the problem persists, contact your software provider.
>
> Details
>
> > Detailed errors from the package manager follow:
> >
> > installing not available
>
> Close

Evidently I don't have a 'software provider', and the returned message gives me nowhere to look. I have tried from a standard and administrator account, so it is not simple permissions. What causes this type of error?

Another user having this issue that is unresolved:

> https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=64919&p=273048

and another, marked 'solved' with no answer:

> https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/cant-install-apps-from-centos-7-4-in-gnome-4175614398/

and a third talking about needing EPEL:

> https://linuxacademy.com/community/posts/show/topic/22176-dabbled-for-a-while-trying-to-get-serious

that I already have:

```
# yum install epel-release-noarch
...
Package epel-release-7-11.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
#
```

**Update:**

Using `yum --enablerepo="epel" install qt-creator` worked just fine to install Qt Creator. Also observed that even though `epel` is installed, `yum repolist` only referenced `epel` in

```
rhscl-python33-epel-7-x86_64                    Python 3.3 - epel-7-x86_64
```

has something mucked up my `epel` installation?

Answer (score -1):

Open terminal and run the following command:

```
sudo yum clean all
```

Then open Application Manager again.
Hope this resolves the issue for you.